# Can you string methods in Backbone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

Suppose I'd like to `where` and `pluck` my bird of an app.

First I'd like to find all `word_type`s that are nouns.

Then I'd like to pluck the `word` attribute, so that the final result is :

All words that are nouns.

```
["Lion", "Capybara", "Cat"]
```

When I try :

```
@words = new Project.Collections.WordsCollection()
@words.where(word_type: "noun").pluck("word_type")
```

It returns :

```
this.words.where({word_type: "noun"}).pluck is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `where` returns an array of models and that array doesn't have any Underscore methods mixed into it. You could unroll the `pluck` (which is really just specific type of `map`):

```
_(@words.where(work_type: 'noun')).map (m) -> m.attributes.word_type
```

or use the [Underscore mixins](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods):

```
@chain()
    .filter((m) -> m.attributes.word_type == 'noun')
    .map((m) -> m.attributes.word_type)
    .value()
```

Or, since you're filtering and plucking the same thing, you count the matches and build your array after:

```
n = @reduce(
    ((n, m) -> n += (if m.attributes.word_type == 'noun' then 1 else 0)),
    0
)
matches = ('noun' for i in [0 ... n])
```

Comment: why not use the `chain` method of `_ js` it would allow as op wanted to

Comment: @Deeptechtons: `@chain().filter...` is Underscore's `chain` but you can't chain `where` or `pluck` the way he wants to, hence the `filter` and `map` versions of `where` and `pluck`.

Comment: In your first example, what is `m`? That is undefined so to speak. Wouldn't that be same for the second and third?

Comment: @Trip: `m` is the model in all three. The `where` method gives you an array of models then that array is wrapped in `_()`; Underscore's [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) passes each element to the callback function.